# How to run jBehave tests on Multiple Browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser, selenium, jbehave

I currently run the JBehave Selenium tests on current browser, I use the PropertyWebDriverProvider() to set up my browser.
There is my code:

public class PlayerLandingPageRunner extends JUnitStories {

```
private WebDriverProvider driverProvider = new PropertyWebDriverProvider();
private WebDriverSteps lifecycleSteps = new PerStoriesWebDriverSteps(driverProvider);
private Pages pages = new Pages(driverProvider);
private SeleniumContext context = new SeleniumContext();
private ContextView contextView = new LocalFrameContextView().sized(500, 100);

public PlayerLandingPageRunner() {
    if ( lifecycleSteps instanceof PerStoriesWebDriverSteps ){
        configuredEmbedder().useExecutorService(MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
        configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(asList("-skip"));
    }
}

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();
    return new SeleniumConfiguration()
            .useSeleniumContext(context)
            .useWebDriverProvider(driverProvider)
            .useStepMonitor(new SeleniumStepMonitor(contextView, context, new SilentStepMonitor()))
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                .withCodeLocation(codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                .withDefaultFormats()
                .withFormats(CONSOLE, TXT, HTML, XML));
}
```

...

How can I set it up to run on other browsers? IE, Chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass "browser" system property to JVM with one of the values described [here](http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/javadoc/web-selenium/org/jbehave/web/selenium/PropertyWebDriverProvider.html).

**Here is how you could set up your tests to run on Chrome.**

If you are running in command line, just pass it like this

```
java -Dbrowser=chrome ...
```

If you are using Eclipse, open *Run Configurations*, select configuration you use for running tests and append into *VM arguments* text box `-Dbrowser=chrome`.

Comment: I am getting the error:
"(org.jbehave.web.selenium.DelegatingWebDriverProvider$DelegateWebDriverNotFound: WebDriver has not been found for this thread.
Please verify you are using the correct WebDriverProvider, with the appropriate credentials if using remote access, e.g. to SauceLabs.)"

Shall I change the PropertyWebDriverProvider to something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Hello Paule. I have the very same issue (webdriver has not been found for this thread...). Have you eventually sorted it out?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately not.